# how to solve Django environment process error

Tags: environment

pipenv : The term 'pipenv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- pipenv install django
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pipenv:String) [], CommandNotFoundException    
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This will help:

First, remove your current version of virtualenv: pip uninstall virtualenv
Then, remove your current version of pipenv: pip uninstall pipenv
When you are asked Proceed (y/n)? just enter y. This will give you a clean slate.
Finally, you can once again install pipenv and its dependencies: pip install pipenv
Check installation with pipenv --version